# Galaxy S5 - Exchange email - How to sort by sender or by date ascending?

Tags: email, exchange, samsung-galaxy-s-5

Galaxy S5 - Exchange email - How to sort by sender or by date ascending?
The sort option is removed.
The filter option does not allow options for sender.
I want email oldest on top, newest on bottom and can't reverse it.
Help? Please/Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is apparently not an option in that particular app. However, there are plenty of third-party alternatives for email. I personally recommend [Boxer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.boxer.email&hl=en).